# How to call destroy action from a link inside a Mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a Subscriber model which is created when somebody subscribes. And by that time, I send the subscriber(person) an email that informs about the subscription.
In that mail I'd like to include a link to delete the subscription but I could not get it in the destroy action, instead it goes to the show action.

my link_to code in mailer template is this

```
= link_to 'this link', controller: "subscribers", action: "destroy", id: @subscription, token: @subscription.token, only_path: false
```

I'd like to to call the destroy action to be able to remove the subscription.

I tried googling but haven't found an example of a delete action called through a mailer

by the way, I use mailcatcher to test the mailer

**UPDATE**

here is my destroy action code as requested

```
def destroy
  #@subscriber being fetch through before filter
  @subscriber.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Subscription was deleted."
  redirect_to subscribers_path 
end
```

Id like to add that there are administrators that could also delete subscribers which already works...

Comment: The current link that I produce is something like this:

http://localhost:3000/subscribers/25?token=f834c59ba9833979

just has to be a delete request T.T

Comment: Post your controller code of `destroy action`.

Comment: change your link_to as `link_to 'this link', controller: "subscribers", action: "destroy", id: @subscriber, token: @subscription.token, only_path: false`

Comment: Also post your full controller code

Comment: @Pavan
https://gist.github.com/lyc4n/28e7e6f6bd40d33e2b2e

Comment: Then changing your link_to as `link_to 'this link', controller: "subscribers", action: "destroy", id: @subscriber, token: @subscriber.token, only_path: false` should work

Comment: @Pavan The ` = link_to 'this link', controller: "subscribers", action: "destroy", id: @subscription, token: @subscription.token, only_path: false` is inside a mailer view and the @subscription variable is being set on the SubscriptionMailer and not in the controller. I am using resque_mailer by the way.. though maybe a bad naming to confuse about subscription and subscriber, but in the current context they are basically the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry It seems that the question is somehow a duplicate...
[can't generate delete link in rails mailing view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123905/cant-generate-delete-link-in-rails-mailing-view)

> The reason is not working, i think, is because the :method => :delete
>   is handled with javascript, and since the link is clicked from the
>   email, javascript is not triggered. The way I would have try to solve
>   this is by passing a parameter to the url like "delete=true" and
>   handle it with that in the controller.

So what I did is created a new route

```
resources subscribers do
  member do
    get :unsubscribe
  end
end
```

in the mailer view i used

```
link_to 'this link', controller: "subscribers", action: "unsubscribe", id: @subscription, token: @subscription.token, only_path: false
```

I'll just use paranoid to mark the subscription deleted. That would be the difference between the destroy and unsubscribe action..

**UPDATE**

Also another pattern which is widely used, is that the link from the email redirects to a form (with put, post or delete request) to your application. And it is what i finally did.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
= link unsubscribe_subscribtions_url(@subscription, token: @subscription.token)
```

app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb

```
class SubscriptionsController
  . . .
  def unsubscribe
    unless params[:token]
      @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:token])
      @subscription.destroy if @subscription.token == params[:token]
      redirect_to subscriptions_path, flash: { notice: 'Your email was unsubscribed' }
    end
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
. . .
resources :subsriptions do
  collection do
    get :unsubscribe # http://example.com/subscriptions/unsubscribe?token=xxxxxx
  end
end
. . .
```

Something like that

Comment: I'm not sure if the destroy_resource_path 
was in earlier version of rails.
But now I use rails 4.0 and the destroy_subscribtions_url
is not available.
only  DELETE /subscribers/:id(.:format)  is available



The destroy_subscriptions_url is not available in my rake routes.

Comment: Yep, i did it but heres what i got:
https://gist.github.com/lyc4n/7f2a89bc6fe22321db91

Comment: Yep, i forgot in rails 4 it was changed to `= link_to subscribtion_url(@subscription, token: @subscription.token), method: :delete`

Comment: Wow, i also found gem for your purpose of unsubscribing email, take a look https://github.com/ankane/mailkick?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: this gem looks great, but i'd like to know if sending a delete request through the mailer is possible and if not i would use this gem

Comment: sorry, i also forgot that the link will be in email. I will edit my answer in 5 mins.